# Use Async Library with MongoDB using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

When I make an API call, I want to update 2 separate collections with MongoDB. The official way of thing this will be using transactions but because this is a prototype for now, I will just use 2 separate function calls to update each collection.

Here is what I am doing:

```
 async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null);
    }, function(callback) {
       connectToDatabase(MONGODB_URI)
      .then(db => updateDocument1(arguments))
      .then(result => {
        callback(null);
      });
    }
    , function(callback) {
       connectToDatabase(MONGODB_URI)
      .then(db => updateDocument2(arguments))
      .then(result => {
        callback(null);
      });
    , function(err, result) {
       callback(null, null)
    }
  ])
```

But somehow, it does not execute updateDocument2. Also, updateDocument1 stops in the middle of the process, so none of documents are updated.
Do you know why? And Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

> async parallel : do function execution parallelly without dependent of
>   other function
>
> async series : do function execution in series (one by one)
>
> async waterfall : do first function execution then pass output of
>   first function as input to next function

now in your case : if updating two collection not depending on each other you can use async parallel

Comment: even i do parellel, none gets executed because the function prematurely exits. I am using AWS Lambda

Comment: add console log and make sure you are getting results from database